# How to insert a variable value into server 2008 table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

Using *Sql Server 2008*: I want to insert a *specific* value (for example: *3513CB65-7FF4-477D-B518-E7FF7B298CB*) to a `uniqueidentifier` field of a table.

How can to declare the value and how to insert it?

Comment: You are trying to do this in C#?

Comment: First of all the question has `c#` and `asp.net` tags but not `sql` or `sql server`. Second; How are you trying to *insert*? Have you tried anything at all? If so please present..

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`NEWID()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) function of `TSQL` as;

```
DECLARE @myUid uniqueidentifier
SET @myUid = NEWID()

INSERT INTO [MYTABLE] (UNIQUEIDENTIFIER_FIELD, SOME_OTHER_FIELD)
VALUES (@myUid, 'some other field data')
```

Or you could even use `NEWID()` directly in *INSERT* statement as:

```
INSERT INTO [MYTABLE] (UNIQUEIDENTIFIER_FIELD, SOME_OTHER_FIELD)
VALUES (NEWID(), 'some other field data')
```

---

Edit: For hardcoded value, you need to use *single quotes* (`'`) as;

```
INSERT INTO [MYTABLE] (UNIQUEIDENTIFIER_FIELD, SOME_OTHER_FIELD)
VALUES ('3513CB65-7FF4-477D-B518-E7FF7B298CB2', 'some other field data')
```

Comment: Actually i need to insert the manual id for example = 3513CB65-7FF4-477D-B518-E7FF7B298CB2; how can insert this id to the field with datatype  Uniqueidentifier ?

Comment: @user3340320 Check edit, and include further details in your question using `edit` option.

Comment: @downvoter Can you please drop a comment about which part is wrong, so it can be corrected / improved.

Comment: @user3340320 Glad it helped and welcome to SO. You can accept the answer you found much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**See example :**

```
-- 1) Declare variables
DECLARE @FirstName varchar(25)   

-- 2) Initialize variables
SET @FirstName = 'Kris'    

-- 3) Execute INSERT command
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Customer] ([FirstName], [id])
VALUES (@FirstName, NEWID())
GO
```

Comment: I guess i'm missing something. Which part of this is about `uniqueidentifier` data type?